# Java I cannot make new lines at the right places

Tags: java

I'm a very beginner. I want to program : print maximum 10 numbers by each line. The numbers are between 20 and 500. The numbers(integers) should be divided 4 and 8 same time.
I programmed as the following.

```
    int num = 20, i;


    while (num <=500){

        for( i = 1; i <=10; i++){
            if (num % 4 == 0 & num % 8 == 0) {                  
                System.out.print(num +",");
            }

            num += 1;

        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
```

However, the result doesn't show as I expected. Could you tell me why the program is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: please insert an example output.

Comment: "doesn't show as I expected" - that hardly tells us anything. What did you expect? What actually happened? What debugging have you done to diagnose the issue? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: please explain what output you want. this smells like homework though!

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was not enough good. The output which I expected was exactly the same as Nishanthi put (the answer bellow), except the first line (9 numbers not 10). It's not homework but an exercise from the last course. I could not succeed some exercises duirng the course. Now I have been reapeating them to understand about for and while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per divisibility rule, if a number is a multiple of 8, it is also a multiple of 4. Hence, you need not check for modulus. Also since you know you want to increment by 8 only, you can automatically do that without incrementing one by one..

Ideally You have to do:

```
      int num = 24, count=0;  // Initializing the first number to be 24, since it is divisible by both 8 and 4.
      while (num <=500)
      {
          System.out.print(num +","); 
          count++; // Incrementing the record count
          num +=8; // Adding 8 to the existing number
          if (count == 10)
          {
              System.out.println(""); // A new line after every tenth record
              count=1; // Count is reset here
          }
      }
```

**Output:**

```
24,32,40,48,56,64,72,80,88,96,
104,112,120,128,136,144,152,160,168,
176,184,192,200,208,216,224,232,240,
248,256,264,272,280,288,296,304,312,
320,328,336,344,352,360,368,376,384,
392,400,408,416,424,432,440,448,456,
464,472,480,488,496,
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Nishanthi. Comments in your program helped me to understand well also. Specially, "if (count == 10)" and "count = 1". Before I could not stop printing out numbers more than 500. I was printing out 560 568... Thanks.

Comment: @sato: You can accept this as answer by checking the grey tick box beside this answer.

Comment: :Sorry it was my first time to use this site. I did not get how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand yout issue, this should solve it:

```
   int num = 20, i;
    int count =0;
    while (num <= 500) {

      if (count ==10) {
        System.out.println();
        count=0;
      }
        if (num % 4 == 0 & num % 8 == 0) {
          System.out.print(num + ",");
          count++;
       }
        num += 1;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Jens. I should use "if(count == 10)", not "for (i=0; i<=10, i++)" and put "if (count == 10 )" not for printing out numbers more than 500(500 not included).

Comment: @sato Sorry i do not understand what you want.